# Switching directory iterator to recursive for the same loop?

Tags: c++, filesystems

Is it possible to switch between recursive and non-recursive version of directory iterator in the same loop? The reason I want to do it because I don't really want to repeat my whole code just for a recursive version.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string DirPath = "C:\\Users";

    // Switch loop to recusive
    bool isRecursive = false;

    // ERROR: Not working
    auto it = isRecursive ? std::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator(DirPath) : 
       std::filesystem::directory_iterator(DirPath);

    for (const auto& entry : it) {

        if (std::filesystem::is_regular_file(entry)) {

            // .......
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not work, since those two iterators have different types and are not convertible to a common type. Hence `auto` cannot now, what type it should be. You have two possibilietes:

The `recursive_directory_iterator` hast the method [`disable_recursion_pending`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/recursive_directory_iterator/disable_recursion_pending), that disables recursion until the next increment, so you would have to call it once per loop.

The problem "I have two very similar things that do nearly the same but are not exactly the same and I don't want to write my code two times." is perfect for applying templates. Write a method

```cpp
template<typename DirectoryIter>
void iter_dir(DirectoryIter it)
{ /* your code */ }

void iter_dir(const std::string& DirPath, bool recursive) // So you don't have to construct the iterators in your caller code
{
    if(recursive)
        iter_dir(std::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator(DirPath));
    else
        iter_dir(std::filesystem::directory_iterator(DirPath));
}
```

Personally I prefer the second variant. I find it neater then hitting the recursive iterator in each iteration.